# Set errors manually in a Reactive Form and update the template in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to set the errors on a `FormControl` from the `.ts` code of the component like this:

```
this.location.setErrors({ invalidLocation: true });
```

But when the `.setErrors()` is called the template is not updating nor displaying the errors until I click the screen for example (togge change detection). So to update the form I need to call the `detectChanges()` from the `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Is this the correct behavior or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks.